# RXJS. Get value from media stream every few seconds

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I currently have an observable (called videoStreams.currentTime$) that is emitting a video player's current position less than every second. How can I get the current time (the value emitted by the observable), but only every 5 seconds or so?

This is the closest I have gotten, but the amount of times the result is emitted, increases each time a value is emitted.

```
const int = interval(5000);

const subscription = int
  .pipe(flatMap(() => videoStreams.currentTime$))
  .subscribe(val => console.log("TIME", val));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your purpose but can you use `switchMap` instea of `flatMap` and tell us the results ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `switchMap` instead

"The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed. " [read more on switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nxbtn)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { interval,of } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap,switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  currentTime$ = of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
  ngOnInit() {
    const int = interval(5000);

    const subscription = int
      .pipe(switchMap(() => this.currentTime$ ))
      .subscribe(val => console.log("TIME", val));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be simple using the following

```
 const curTime$ = videoStreams.currentTime$.pipe(
  throttle(() => interval(10000))
);
```

Instead of returning the position of the player every third of a second or so, it returns the value at the point in time (that i assign to it) by throttling it.

Comment: is this from a stream from a `<video>` elm? Would you be so gracious as to setup a Stackblitz for your answer?